# Adding jQuery live search to dynamic inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, live

I am using the jQuery live search plugin and need to bind it to all instances of a class. My class instances may or may not be dynamic.

I know I can accomplish binding it to the dynamic class instances by nesting it within a jQuery Live function, E.G `$(".myLink").live(click function(){});`

However, I also need the non dynamic classes to have the binding as well.

How can I accomplish this without defining my liveSearch binding twice? (Once at document ready for the static elements, and once in my click handler for the dynamic elements).

Here's my liveSearch code, not sure if it matters.

```
$(".myClass").liveSearch({
url: 'foo.php',
id: 'liveSearchID',
parent: '.myParent',
});
```

Thanks much.

Comment: A bit more information or rather code explanatory would be helpful...

Comment: Sorry, thought I was clear. I need to bind liveSearch to classes that do not yet exist in the dom.

Comment: Which livesearch plugin do you use? [There are quite a few](https://www.google.com/search?q=liveSearch+jQuery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery `.on()` to bind `liveSearch`  to present (non dynamic) or future elements like :

```
$("#parentContainer").on("click", ".myClass", function(){
  $(this).liveSearch({
     // options
  }); // liveSearch
}); // on
```

**Notice** that you have to apply `.on()` to the **parent container** of your selector `.myClass` and then pass the event, `.myClass` as descendant selector and the handler.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BBjGS/)**

`.on()` requires jQuery 1.7+

**EDIT** (Dec 15, 2012 - 4:13pm PT):

Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()` ... so just tweak your code this way `.delegate(selector, eventType, handler)` (still applying `.delegate()` to the parent container) like :

```
$("#parentContainer").delegate(".myClass", "click", function() {
  $(this).liveSearch({
     // options
  }); // liveSearch
}); // delegate
```

See new **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xzSMW/)** using `.delegate()` (requires jQuery v1.4.2+)

Comment: Thanks JFK, I am stuck on an older version of jQuery, can this be replicated with live()?