# Resig's Live Search redux for jQuery 1.7 and above?

Tags: jquery, search, livesearch, quicksilver, resig

I recently found Resig's jQuery [rewrite of a Quicksilver Live Search](http://ejohn.org/apps/livesearch/) and love the workings of it... but I'm trying to update it to work with the new .on() event handler. However my abilities (or lack thereof) fail me.

I'm thinking I need to edit the "this.keyup(filter)..." but I get nothin' to work. Any ideas?

**Update:** Just a point of clarification. My thoughts as to wanting to update the script is to accept list items brought in dynamically. Everything works fine as long as it's a static list, but since I have introduced a list created via an ajax call, it fails to work. I'm going to mock up a fiddle and link it here shortly. In the meantime, if anyone can help me out, it'd save my hide. Thanks.

```
jQuery.fn.liveUpdate = function(list){
    list = jQuery(list);

    if ( list.length ) {
    var rows = list.children('li'),
        cache = rows.map(function(){
        //return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        return $('a', this)[0].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        });

    this
        .keyup(filter).keyup()
        .parents('form').submit(function(){
            return false;
        });

    }

    return this;

    function filter(){
        var term = jQuery.trim( jQuery(this).val().toLowerCase() ), scores = [];

        if ( !term ) {
            rows.show();
        } else {
            rows.hide();

            cache.each(function(i){
                var score = this.score(term);
                if (score > 0) { scores.push([score, i]); }
            });

            jQuery.each(scores.sort(function(a, b){return b[0] - a[0];}), function(){
                jQuery(rows[ this[1] ]).show();
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

So by chance I ran across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13887697/adding-jquery-live-search-to-dynamic-inputs) which, with the assistance of [jfk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055987/jfk), pretty much summed up what I was looking for. I was wanting to make the script run after dynamic content was created, when what I should have been doing was call the script when the user is wanting to make a search.

```
$('#staticParent').on("click", "#searchField", function(){
    $(this).livesearch("#dynamicElements").focus();
});
```

Any additional info from more advanced developers on making this better, I'm all ears. I hope this can one day help another. :)